# make condition if in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I work with oracle

I want to make condition if in my sql query

this my sql query :

```
SELECT unit.id_unit AS id, 
       unitLang.abbreviated_name_unit||  ' - ' ||unitLang.name_unit_lang
 AS name_unit_lang 
 FROM unit unit 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN employee on  employee.id_unit =  unit.id_unit
 LEFT OUTER JOIN unit_lang unitLang on  unitLang.id_unit =  unit.id_unit
 LEFT OUTER JOIN security_employee_unit secUnit ON unit.id_unit = secUnit.id_unit 
 where unitLang.lang_unit_lang  = 'ar' and 
       unit.statut = '1' and 
       employee.id_employe = 'EM-000008' or 
       secUnit.id_employee = 'EM-000008' AND 
       secUnit.type = 'S'
```

I want to add a test

this is my test :

if unit.id_unit = 'allorg'  the query  will  have this syntax :

```
 SELECT unit.id_unit AS id, 
        unitLang.abbreviated_name_unit||  ' - ' ||unitLang.name_unit_lang
 AS name_unit_lang  
 FROM unit_lang unitLang, unit unit
 where unit.id_unit = unitLang.id_unit and 
       unitLang.lang_unit_lang  = 'ar' and 
       unit.statut = '1'
```

how can I make this test in my query

**Updated :**

I want to deveop a function :

in this function first  I should run this query

```
 SELECT unit.id_unit AS id, 
           unitLang.abbreviated_name_unit||  ' - ' ||unitLang.name_unit_lang
     AS name_unit_lang 
     FROM unit unit 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN employee on  employee.id_unit =  unit.id_unit
     LEFT OUTER JOIN unit_lang unitLang on  unitLang.id_unit =  unit.id_unit
     LEFT OUTER JOIN security_employee_unit secUnit ON unit.id_unit = secUnit.id_unit 
     where unitLang.lang_unit_lang  = 'ar' and 
           unit.statut = '1' and 
           employee.id_employe = 'EM-000008' or 
           secUnit.id_employee = 'EM-000008' AND 
           secUnit.type = 'S'
```

then I want to make test related to result of the first query :

if unit.id_unit = 'allorg'

the result of my function should have the result of this query

```
SELECT unit.id_unit AS id, 
            unitLang.abbreviated_name_unit||  ' - ' ||unitLang.name_unit_lang
     AS name_unit_lang  
     FROM unit_lang unitLang, unit unit
     where unit.id_unit = unitLang.id_unit and 
           unitLang.lang_unit_lang  = 'ar' and 
           unit.statut = '1'
```

Comment: Use stored procedures. And make dynamic queries

Comment: Sorry, your question is bit unclear. Can you reword it?

Comment: What do you finally want to return back from your function ?

Comment: Your query is almost certainly not doing what you want, even if we could figure out what you're going for - your `LEFT JOIN`s are being turned into regular `INNER JOIN`s due to the conditions in the `WHERE` clause, and that `OR` is probably throwing things off too (`AND`s are evaluated first!).  Give us sample starting and result data please.

Answer (score 0):

Does the first query return only one value?
If yes, you can assign that result into a variable(which you have to declare in the same function).

```
declare 
var_unit_id varchar2(50);
var_other varchar2(250);
begin
SELECT unit.id_unit AS id, 
           unitLang.abbreviated_name_unit||  ' - ' ||unitLang.name_unit_lang AS name_unit_lang 
into var_unit_id, var_other

     FROM unit unit 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN employee on  employee.id_unit =  unit.id_unit
     LEFT OUTER JOIN unit_lang unitLang on  unitLang.id_unit =  unit.id_unit
     LEFT OUTER JOIN security_employee_unit secUnit ON unit.id_unit = secUnit.id_unit 
     where unitLang.lang_unit_lang  = 'ar' and 
           unit.statut = '1' and 
           employee.id_employe = 'EM-000008' or 
           secUnit.id_employee = 'EM-000008' AND 
           secUnit.type = 'S';
```

Now you can check like

```
if var_unit_id = 'allorg' then
--put your code here
SELECT unit.id_unit AS id, 
            unitLang.abbreviated_name_unit||  ' - ' ||unitLang.name_unit_lang
     AS name_unit_lang  
     FROM unit_lang unitLang, unit unit
     where unit.id_unit = unitLang.id_unit and 
           unitLang.lang_unit_lang  = 'ar' and 
           unit.statut = '1'
end if;
```

But then a function will return only one value, but your resulting query returns two values. How are you deciding to get the returned value?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, just a single query will work

```
SELECT unit.id_unit AS id, 
            unitLang.abbreviated_name_unit||  ' - ' ||unitLang.name_unit_lang
     AS name_unit_lang  
     FROM unit_lang unitLang, unit unit
     where unit.id_unit = unitLang.id_unit and 
           unitLang.lang_unit_lang  = 'ar' and 
           unit.statut = '1' and
           exists (SELECT 'x' 
                         FROM unit unit 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN employee on  employee.id_unit =  unit.id_unit
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN unit_lang unitLang on  unitLang.id_unit =  unit.id_unit
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN security_employee_unit secUnit ON unit.id_unit = secUnit.id_unit 
                         where unitLang.lang_unit_lang  = 'ar' and 
                               unit.statut = '1' and 
                               (employee.id_employe = 'EM-000008' or ecUnit.id_employee = 'EM-000008') AND 
                               secUnit.type = 'S' and 
                               unit.id_unit = 'allorg');
```